# How to send 13 bit LIN (Local Interconnect Network ) Break?

Tags: communication, nxp, lin

I use MC9S08DZ96 MCU (NXP). I wrote the corresponding registers to create a break at the beginning of the data LIN frame. The data frame is sent correctly, but the problem is that the break part is not 13 bits. I set the break registers like this:

```c
if (SCI1S1_TDRE == 0U) {            
    return ERR_TXFULL;              
}
SCI1C2_SBK = 0x01U;                
SCI1C2_SBK = 0x00U;
```

SBK is:

[image]

Then I send 0x55 and ID:

```c
while(1) {
    if (SCI1S1_TDRE == 0U) {       
        return ERR_TXFULL;            
    }

    SCI1C2_SBK = 0x01U;             
    SCI1C2_SBK = 0x00U;                 
    
    delayy(10);
    c = AS1_SendChar(Sync_);
    delayy(10);
    c = AS1_SendChar(ID_);
    delayy(333);
}
```

I initialized these registers:

```c
void AS1_Init(void)
{
    SerFlag = 0x00U;        /* Reset flags */

    /* SCI1C1: LOOPS=1,SCISWAI=0,Rsrc=1,M=0,WAKE=1,ILT=0,PE=0,PT=0 */
    setReg8(SCI1C1, 0xA8U); /* Configure the SCI */ 

    /* SCI1C3: R8=0,T8=0,TXDIR=1,TXINV=0,ORIE=0,NEIE=0,FEIE=0,PEIE=0 */
    setReg8(SCI1C3, 0x20U); /* Disable error interrupts */ 

    /* SCI1C2: TIE=0,TCIE=0,RIE=0,ILIE=0,TE=0,RE=0,RWU=0,SBK=0 */
    setReg8(SCI1C2, 0x00U); /* Disable all interrupts */ 

    /* SCI1S2: LBKDIF=0,RXEDGIF=0,??=0,RXINV=0,RWUID=0,BRK13=1,LBKDE=0,RAF=0 */
    setReg8(SCI1S2, 0x04U);

    SCI1BDH = 0x00U;        /* Set high divisor register (enable device) */
    SCI1BDL = 0x1AU;        /* Set low divisor register (enable device) */
    SCI1C2_TE = 0x01U;      /* Enable transmitter */
    SCI1C2_RE = 0x01U;
}
```

BRK13 defines for us that the break length is 13. If you have noticed in the registers above, I have set it.

> setReg8(SCI1S2, 0x04U);

Finally, the frame LIN is like this:

[image]

Break is correctly sent, also 0x55, 0x34 for sync and ID, respectively. But the break length is not 13 bits. what is the reason?

Comment: Perhaps the break can be any length as long as it's at least 13 bit times long?

Comment: So, what length is the break then if it's not 13 bits?

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Actually, frame LIN should have 13 bits or more 0 for break. But the datasheet states that if it is BRK13=1 , 13 zero bits are sent as a break.

Comment: @brhans It is 9 bits.